# Jenkins, possible to set Jenkins to job to require password?

Tags: jenkins

Some of our Jenkins jobs are such that they deploy e.g. to a client acceptance test environment. It is very important that this type of jobs are not triggered by accident. Is it therefore possible to configure Jenkins to somehow require a password when triggering a specific build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up [Project based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/2012/01/03/Allow+access+to+specific+projects+for+Users%28Assigning+security+for+projects+in+Jenkins%29), then you can restrict build access on a per-job basis.

*From the help on the Jenkins configuration page:*

> [Project based security] is an extension to "Matrix-based security"
>   that allows additional ACL matrix to be defined for each project
>   separately (which is done on the job configuration screen.)
>
> This allows you to say things like "Joe can access project A, B, and C
>   but he can't see D." See the help of "Matrix-based security" for the
>   concept of matrix-based security in general.
>
> ACLs are additive, so the access rights granted below will be
>   effective for all the projects.*

Comment: it is not an answer for its question. 
problem is not restrict access for the team, problem is to double check build process for granted users.

Answer (score 1):

ok. 
my 5cents about this question.

Our Jenkins uses Redmine's mysql db as auth input.

in Jenkins you'll need next plugins:

- [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)
- [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)

and after activating `Password` parameter, you'll be asked for it before build.

So, i figured out 2 options.

1. It is applicable, if your slaves has direct connection with mysql (or any DB engine).

then pre-build check:

```
SALT=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file="~/redmcheck.my" -B -se "select salt from redmine.users where login='${BUILD_USER}';")
HASH=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file="~/redmcheck.my" -B -se "select hashed_password from redmine.users where login='${BUILD_USER}';")
CHECK=$(sha1 -qs $SALT$(sha1 -qs $Password))

if [ $HASH != $CHECK ] 
then
  exit 1;
fi
```

It will broke build, if your entered password doesn't equal.

2. Second solution, is to use Rest API in Redmine.
   And it allows to recheck user on remote slaves.

   CODE=$(curl -X GET -u ${BUILD_USER}:${Password} --write-out "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null -s https://redmine/users/current.json);
   if [ $CODE != "200" ] 
   then
       exit 1;
   fi

If it gets 200 code, so it goes build.

Comment: Not particularly applicable in my situation, but I like the thought you put into the solution :).